# How to do HTML5 validation on <select> element styled with Uniform.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-uniform

I'm having trouble with HTML5 validation on `<select>` element styled with Uniform.js. With unstyled `<select>`, in Chrome for example, I would get small popup saying "Please select and item in the list" if I try to submit the form without selecting something first. Unfortunately, when Uniform is applied this popup is gone and I get no validation message.

How we could fix this issue? Thanks.

JSFiddle with one unstyled and one styled `<select>` element for testing can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Klikerko/hqUr8/

**EDIT:** After more testing it turns out that validation message doesn't show in Chrome on Mac (version 25). This issue might be fixed in newer Chrome, but I have to use this older version because of some problems with CodeKit and latest Chrome.

Comment: It's working... http://i.imgur.com/V25eJ9w.png

(HTML5 form validation stops at the first invalid field.)

Comment: @Brian you are correct. Looks like it's not working only on my Chrome on Mac. I just test in FF on PC and validation message is displayed, but at a top of the page or at a bottom.